# AddThis share button wont work in DotNetNuke

Tags: javascript, dotnetnuke, addthis

For some reason when I add a HTML module (well the default module added to DNN 5.4) and then add the "AddThis" javascript. While the button shows up clicking on it opens up a new page rather than showing an iframe modal message or on hover a list of popular social media networks to share the page with. Wonder what would be the easiest way to resolve this and why this happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a complete answer, but to me it sounds like the AddThis javascript code is never loaded by the browser. When viewing the web page that doesn't workg, open the HTML source and look for the AddThis script tag. It probably should look something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js#username=..."></script>
```

If you can not find it, then there is something to work on. If you find it, try to open the URL in your browser and see if you get the javascript.

Otherwise: as always, FireBug (or the tools in IE8) is your friend.

Comment: You are right. And the reason it doesn't happen is when you are in rich text view and adding this - it tries to be smart and removes few things from the code. 
Solution - Click basic text view , then html from bottom, then insert your add this code and then save.

Answer (score 0):

Try copying the addthis script reference and pasting it to the page header tags:

http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js#pub=AddThis